# Xamarin forms tabbed paged swipe invoke event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, swipe, tabbedpage

I am using Xamarin forms to create a TabbedPage. The problem is that I want to swipe between tabs and this is disable by default. I found one class called ExtendedTabbedPage which has one attribute called SwipeEnable and some methods that invoke the swipe event. 
This is my class that extends from ExtendedTabbedPage and creates two tabs with some content. I set the value of swipeEnabled attribute but it does not do anything. Is there anyway to invoke the swipe event from this class?

```
public class TabbedPageComplete: ExtendedTabbedPage
{       
    public TabbedPageComplete ()
    {
        this.Title = "TabbedPage";
        this.SwipeEnabled = true;
        this.Children.Add (new ContentPage 
            {
                Title = "Blue",
                Content = new BoxView
                {
                    Color = Color.Blue,
                    HeightRequest = 100f,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                },
            }
        );
        this.Children.Add (new ContentPage {
            Title = "Blue and Red",
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    new BoxView { Color = Color.Blue },
                    new BoxView { Color = Color.Red}
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tested with iOS also or just with Android ?
The ExtendedTabbedPage is currently only implemented for iOS [ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.cs](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.iOS/Controls/ExtendedTabbedPage/ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.cs) while [for Android is still under development](https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Droid/Controls).

Comment: No I did not test in iOS as I need to do it in Android. so is there no way to do it?

Comment: You can leave your code as is, the feature will be implemented in a later release of the library. Until then, you might want to try customize the Carousel Page > http://bit.ly/ZQTVuu